# How do people test Kube config locally (Kustomize)

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, kubectl, kustomize

### Scenario

We have a large, complex sets of Kustomize with replacements, CRDs, SOPs etc.
We can generate the config locally/CI with

`..\kustomize.exe build --load-restrictor=LoadRestrictionsNone .\path > sample-build.yaml`

But this doesn't test the actual values that will be used. It doesn't detect things like missing config maps.

`kubectl apply -f .\dev-01.sample.yaml --dry-run=server` Could be used but would need a cloud for each developer or the developer to have all the containers locally (e.g. docker).

Are there any commands to 'expand' sample-build.yaml so I can see the actual environment variables that will be passed to the container at deploy time, but, without a cluster locally.

What do other people use to CI Kustomize?

Comment: End-to-End tests. Deploy the application in an E2E with the kustomization (argocd, for example, makes it easy). Aside from testing the application, we implicitly test the deployment.